# HTML: requested same image only once

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading comments of a post. If there are 10 user it will have 10 thumb user image.The problem is if there is same user 5 times its fetch thumb image for the same user 5 times.

Can it be avoided ? i.e for the same user only first time it will fetch user's thumb from server for next 4 times it will use the first thumb image.For the same user i am generating below url for fetching thumb.

```
/photohandler/fetchprofilepics/400004/thumb/8"
/photohandler/fetchprofilepics/400004/thumb/28"
```

Last number `8` `28` is just a random number i have putted this because without this it was not changing image with the updated one

Comment: you can add the cache headers to the thumbs so that only first time it is loaded from the server after that it is loaded from the local cache

Comment: you can use an Expires header to say that the cache is valid for 1 hour or something like that... after that again the image will be fetched from the server so if the thumb was updated the new one will be downloaded... or you can think of a etag or modified since headers to have a validatable cache

Comment: I too had same problem, i too used random profile number to ensure image is downloaded from server. Why don't you want to use random number if it works fine?